# Just how cold is it outside in Snowpiercer?

Tags: snowpiercer

I watched Snowpiercer last night, and I was struck by the seeming contradiction between two scenes.

In the first, a character is forced to stick his bare arm outside of the Snowpiercer. After exactly seven minutes, his arm is withdrawn from the outside. His arm is so frozen over, that it can be completely shattered into pieces with a sledgehammer.

However, at the end of the film: (SPOILERS)

> It's revealed that the Earth has warmed enough that life outside the Snowpiercer is possible. Two characters walk outside with no winter protection except for parkas. While it is intentionally ambiguous whether they DO survive, the underlying assumption is that the cold is at least survivable.

So just how cold is it? Cold enough for a man's arm to be completely frozen after just seven minutes exposure? Or cold enough for the ending to hold any meaning?

Comment: ISTR, they said something like "at this **altitude**, 7 minutes should suffice; everything is colder, at higher altitudes.

Comment: Also, they are in a train. Probably both events took place in different areas, and not all the planet will have the same temperature.

Comment: Also IIRC, the arm-freezing took place at night. The temperature would have been lower than it was at the end of the movie, when the sun was out.

Comment: It's ***really*** cold.

Comment: Except, Mooz, the altitude at the end looks pretty close to mountain peaks, so is probably high too (although, admittedly, the mountains might just *look* super-big, since everything is snow-covered regardless of altitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [2008 interview](http://english.yonhapnews.co.kr/Features/2008/05/27/93/0801000000AEN20080526006100315F.HTML) for YonHapNews, the film's Director (Bong Joon-Ho) referred to the world being approximately **minus 80 degrees Celcius**, more than sufficient to freeze an exposed limb.

> "I remember it was around the end of 2004,” the director said in an
>   interview published by the Yonhap News Agency in 2008. “ It was when I
>   finished 'Memories of Murder' and was working on 'The Host.' I went to
>   a comic book store near Hong-ik University. I go there once or twice a
>   month when I am stressed out. 'Le Transperceneige' suddenly came into
>   my sight, and I read the whole trilogy standing there. I could not
>   wait until I got home to read.
>
> "This train has enraptured me,” he continued. “I believe everyone has
>   a fantasy about trains giving off chugs and puffs, and landscapes
>   viewed from the window. **What you can see from the window in this
>   story, however, is only the world icebound, with minus 80 degrees
>   outside.** Survivors live in the train, but they can't stay in harmony
>   even at a time of adversity.

Answer (score 10):

#### Given the speed at which the man's arm was completely frozen, we can assume the temperature outside is at least -40 degree Fahrenheit. Thanks to the joys of 'wind chill factors' due to air movement, decreasing temperatures to -116 degrees Fahrenheit.

- Even if the train were moving at a mere 40 miles per hour, it would make the apparent temperature a chilling -116 degrees; which should be sufficient to freeze his unprotected arm nearly solid in approximately seven to ten minutes. Altitude may have also part making the temperature even lower.

[image]

> The cooling effect of moving air is well known, the phrase "wind chill factor" was coined by the American Paul Siple to describe the fact that wind increases the rate of heat loss and has the effect of making it seem as though it's really colder than the thermometer is showing.
>
> Siple's original experiments were conducted in Antarctica in 1941 by measuring how long it took water to freeze in baked beans tins in different strengths of wind and at different temperatures.
>
> The use of wind chill is to show the effective temperature at a particular wind speed. For instance in calm conditions at -29°C a well clothed person is in little danger, a light wind of 10mph gives the same effect as a temperature of -44°C when exposed flesh can freeze in a minute or so.
>
> A breeze of 25mph gives an equivalent of -66°C with severe danger to exposed flesh within seconds rather than minutes. This is one of the reasons why Antarctica is such an extreme environment, it is often both very cold and very windy. **REF: [How humans deal with and survive extreme cold](http://www.coolantarctica.com/Antarctica%20fact%20file/science/cold_humans.htm)**

#### SPECULATIONS AND ANALYSIS:

**We are forced to use comparative analysis since we have limited information to work with:**

- We can assume the temperature outside the Snowpiercer is below -30 degrees Fahrenheit. Why? Because, with clothing and shelter, -30 is a survivable temperature for human beings. Uncomfortable, but survivable. If it were only -30 there would be no reason for anyone to be on the Snowpiercer at all. They are there because, it is supposedly inhospitable. We will assume it is at least -40 degrees in all parts of the world, accompanied by strong winds.
- We see a scene where the train is passing by a city with immense snow drifts a good deal of the city under ice and snow. Assuming there is a modest wind, coupled with -40 degree temperatures, and you have your basic inhospitable Antarctic winter.

> - The average temperature in Antarctica is -58 degrees Fahrenheit with winds in winter reaching 40 miles per hour, creating a wind chill factor of -132 degrees Fahrenheit.**

- If we assume a -40 temperature with a modest 15 to 20 mph wind, you are looking at -85 to -96 degrees F. Far colder than your average day in Antarctica, barely able to be survived except by people trained to live in such cold. If the winds are higher, then survival without the train becomes impossible.

Comment: This is a strong "real world" answer but is there anything in the film (or supporting literature) to back this up, e.g. other than some fairly flimsy visual evidence?

Comment: I didn't find any information regarding the film world, its physical conditions or temperatures. Since humans are fairly adaptable and cold tolerant with the right shelter, we can assume certain aspects regarding cold. If there is no shelter that can protect you from the cold it is at least -50 degrees F. This is the underlying premise of the movie. If that doesn't give you a baseline, nothing will.