# In Snowpiercer, could any life survive outside of the train?

Tags: movie, snowpiercer

In a related question is was asked: [Just how cold is it outside in Snowpiercer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71909/35012). Would it be possible for any life to survive outside the train in these extreme temperatures?

> At the end we see that the world is beginning to warm up and there is a polar bear up in the mountains. How could have the bear survived, or was this just a hallucination?

Comment: Are you asking for a realistic, scientific answer? Or just generally in relation to the film?

Comment: @Xantec if there is harder scientific evidence which would allow for such a thing, I would prefer that answer. There may be some other in-universe explanation which could also be accepted such as information from the comic which the film is based from.

Comment: If you want a hard science answer then your question might be better on [biology.se]. That's not to say that hard science isn't welcome here, but it would need to be backed up by the source material.

Comment: @Deion - It was (supposedly) minus 80, which basically means that anything other than the hardiest arctic animals would be dead in fairly short order. Some arctic winters can go as low as -88 Celcius so clearly it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, life (including large animals) was able to survive outside the train. How they do so isn't explained in any great detail.

We know from this [2008 interview](http://english.yonhapnews.co.kr/Features/2008/05/27/93/0801000000AEN20080526006100315F.HTML) for YonHap that the temperature outside the train was supposedly around -80°C, low enough to kill all but the hardiest of [arctic creatures](http://lib.colostate.edu/wildlife/tundra-biome.html).

In a recent interview for [Hitfix](http://www.hitfix.com/news/chris-evans-on-snowpiercer-vod-and-harvey-weinsteins-edit) however, it appears that an early decision taken to show life outside the train was made for financial, rather than story reasons:

> Although the tail section was just one of 60 cars, Choi said only
>   about half of those were actually constructed. He also revealed Bong's
>   initial desire for an on-board zoo. "It's a 60-car train and we see 26
>   cars. That's how many we built. There are definitely a lot of cars
>   that we don't see in the film. We just shot what was in the script,"
>   said Choi. "Whatever filled the narrative needs of whatever particular
>   section we shot. **They asked Bong a bunch of times if there were any
>   cars that he imagined that he didn't shoot and one of them was a zoo
>   section with animals crammed in and a giraffe with his head down to
>   fit inside. That was ultimately abandoned because he wanted to show
>   life at the end. He didn't want to have living animals inside."**

**There's no indication that the ending was anything other than a real depiction of a polar bear**

Answer (score 3):

As with many Sci-Fi films, there are many, many problems with the whole concept of Snowpiercer.

- We had likely an extraordinary situation, a [Snowball/Slushball earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth#Survival_of_life_through_frozen_periods) before 800 million years and life survived uncontested because there are many refugia which are also applicable to humans. First, the equator regions are almost always free of ice and allow survival. Second, oceans can freeze, but ice is an excellent insulator, so as the ice deepens, it inhibits itself the progress of freezing and builds an insulating wall against the cold. Third, the same situation we have on land, you can survive in caverns and underground structures, even in Permafrost. So the premise "*All* people will die because there is no protection against cold" is wrong from the start (That it will cause a mass extinction of humans is undisputed).
- The problem is after having a shelter getting food. Microorganisms in the sea during the Snowball Earth showed that they can thrive unimpended and can therefore sustain the food chain (krill, fish, predators). So at least sea organisms will be able to survive. Land organisms in the coast region like ice bears could feed on sea lions. Problematic will be the sustainance of plants and therefore herbivores on land. If food exists, herbivores can survive in very low temperatures like the Yak or the Yakutian horse with temperatures down to -70 °C. We as humans are with the current knowledge able to produce food fully synthetically (there is a thread in skeptics, I cannot find it now), but we don't do it currently because the natural food is much cheaper and needs much less energy. In fact, using caverns as greenhouses and power the necessary light with nuclear reactors are efficient as well.
- While concrete and wood are able to resist very low temperatures, steel is not quite as forgiving. With the supposed temperatures the wheels and rails of the train would be brittle like glass. Only steel with a high amount of alloys would be able to sustain such temperatures and it would be impossible to build such an extended network of rails because there is not enough material available.
- There is absolutely no reason to use a train because it only has disadvantages: It needs energy to move which can be used for heating or processing, the windchill excerbate the freezing and insulation problem and its infrastructure needs too much sustainment. It's in fact completely idiotic.

Comment: I was wondering about the wheels as well. Unless they are made of some kind of alloy unknown to man, then they should have worn out years ago. Railroad tracks also need constant maintenance as well. Between those two things alone, the train could not have possibly ran constantly for all those years.

Comment: On the other side: If the train is powered by an perpetuum mobile, who am I to deny the possibility that the inventor has a rich ore of unobtainium ?

Comment: Addition: I actually liked the movie and I can enjoy movies with a...problematic...storyline. But sometimes my ratio and common sense cannot suppress muted whimpers.

Comment: @ThorstenS. Snowpiercer is blatantly allegory. Expecting realism from allegory is... ah... an *unskilled* approach to the narrative.

Comment: @Lexible The question asked was explicitly if the shown environment in Snowpiercer (-80°C) were *real* would then life be possible ? You can ignore the last two remarks which are telling what would happen with material exposed to this temperatures as addition. And I must admit I am a bit skeptical to "allegory" defenses; they are highly subjective (J.R.R. Tolkien said definitely LOTR has *nothing* to do with both World Wars and still critics found such an allegory) and shield a work from criticism. I saw Snowpiercer as nice sci-fi action adventure and nothing more.

Comment: @ThorstenS. It is fair to watch the film for "sc-fi action adventure," but "allegory" is not meant as a shield for criticism. Rather, cultural criticism that does not take work *first* on its own terms is a weak broth. I personally dig thinking about realism questions. But if a story is not trying to start in a basis of realism, and Bong is on record discussing [*Snowpiercer* as allegory](http://www.filmcomment.com/entry/interview-bong-joon-ho), then realism is not a fair place to start a critique.

Comment: Point-by-point: 1&2) If there are a few survivors in caves, the people on the train won't know about it, so that's all irrelevant. 3) It's a train that spans the world, easy enough to believe there are new, custom materials involved in its construction. 4) They didn't choose the train to survive, they just happened to be on it when everything froze and have tried to stay alive.

Comment: @DCShannon 1&2: The question was: "*Could* any life survive outside the train?", **not** "Have any people survived outside the train". *Your* points are irrelevant, not mine.

Comment: You're not even addressing that question, though. You're complaining about the "whole concept of Snowpiercer". What does the decision to survive on a train have to do with whether any life could survive outside of the train? If you replaced the first sentence with something addressing the question, and removed the last two bullet points, then it would at least *be* an answer.