# Do the children survive in Snowpiercer?

Tags: snowpiercer

Following from this question: [In Snowpiercer, could any life survive outside of the train?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71948/in-snowpiercer-could-any-life-survive-outside-of-the-train)

Is there any indication that the two children who survived the crash actually survive long enough to procreate?

I'm looking for answers from novels, the writers of the film, or interviews.

I know the filmmaker was optimistic about them surviving, but it's -80C outside and there's polar bears around.  The two children have no survival skills, and are only alive because adults protected them.  Those adults are now dead.

Is there anything that explains if, and how, they survive?

Comment: Could you please clarify why you believe this isn't a dupe of the question you linked? How has that not satisfied what you're looking for?

Comment: Unless the polar bear [hands the children a Coca-Cola](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2nBBMbjS8w) it's hard to see how the situation ends well for anyone but the bear.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait wait... Snowpiercer was *based on a novel?!*

Comment: @Steve-O - A [graphic novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Transperceneige)

Comment: @Mooz - That question explores how live in general survived the global disaster, while the humans were riding around in their train.  It does not discuss how two, young, unskilled children are able to survive that frozen environment following a serious traumatic crash.

Comment: I felt that my answer offered about as much info as we're ever gonna get on 'what happened next'. Is there anything else you'd like me to address before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 4):

According to the film's director the kids not only survived but thrived. Somehow, despite the fact this is well below the [minimum viable population](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18275/how-many-people-are-required-for-a-healthy-re-population-of-the-earth-post-apoc), they were able to repopulate the Earth.

> **Q.** **That's what's so scary! And it takes so long for the train to blow up! There is ... nobody left!**
>
> **Bong Joon-Ho:** *I don't think Nam is an anarchist though. He just wanted to blow up one train car. It's the avalanche that kills everyone else. It's the
> revenge of nature, if you will. Also, avalanches are most prevalent in
> March or April, when the snow is slightly softer, just like in Nam's
> dialogue. That's when avalanches happen, usually. Yes, they're all
> dead, and that's a bit harsh. But it's a sci-fi film: If you can't say
> these things, or have these ideas in a sci-fi film, where can you?*
>
> *The idea of there being multiple generations of people on this train is a key one. There's an expression in the film: "train baby." Those
> are the two kids that survive, the ones that only knew life on the
> train. Someone like Curtis or Nam, they lived on Earth, then boarded
> the train. These kids have never known what it was like to step on the
> earth. So it's almost like Neil Armstrong touching down on the Moon
> when they leave the train for the first time. They have no memory of
> what it's like to be on the Earth. For them to procreate, it's going
> to take a little time. **So, for me, it's a very hopeful ending. But
> of course there are so many deaths, and so many sacrifices ... it's
> not so sweet. But those two kids will spread the human race.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Director Bong Joon-ho Breaks Down Snowpiercer’s Ending](http://www.vulture.com/2014/06/director-bong-joon-ho-talks-snowpiercers-ending.html)</sup></sub>

No explanation is given *how* they managed it, other than that it's [not as cold as previously imagined](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/71965/20774).